# Smart Array 6i in DL385 can only see two physical drives

Tags: hp-smart-array, server-setup

I originally had 2 x 72.8 GB hard drives installed and set up as RAID 0+1 then I added another 4 x 72.8 GB hard drives and it can still only see 2. That applies with both the inbuilt configuration (F8 on startup) and ACU under Windows. What to do?

When I received the DL385 it had no hard drives but did have 4 blanks. That tells me it must have had 2 hard drives in its previous life.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I will do that. Also when I bought the server it had no hard drives and 4 blank caddys so I figure it must have had 2 drives before. I have tried resetting NVRAM and RBSU also ACU from the Smartstart CD all to no avail. It still only sees 2 physical drives.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered there was a cable missing on the SCSI backplane.
The backplane can be configured for simplex or duplex.
In simplex the one controller does for 6 drives.
In duplex one controller does for 2 drives and another for the other 4 drives.
I borrowed a cable from a DL380 and now it can see all 6 drives.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that the bays in the chassis are connected to the raid controller?
Some of the HP's that I have bought didn't ship with the internal sas cable to connect the card to the bays, it was an add on item. For us it was the last 2 bays in a dl360.